# How to take printout from my android app?

Tags: android, printing, printers, network-printers

I have a print button in my app. If I click the button it should print the screen. My problem is if the screen has a scrollview and it has contents more than screen size. It should print the whole content of the screen. the printout may take 2 or 3 pages. Is there any sample code or project for print the screen not by taking photos or screen shots.

I converted My whole data into HTML format and use a WebView to display data
can any one please help me,
Thanks.

Comment: You want to take a screenshot of the entire scroll view?

Comment: hi no i want only printout

Comment: You can take a printout of that image right?

Comment: i am not getting what ur asking

Comment: You can printout after you take a screenshot of the entire page right?

Comment: ya but in my application i have one print button if i click print button it will print my current page via wifi

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck at then?

Comment: i will tell u clearly

Comment: i created one registration for using html after that if i click register button it will store into database and again iam retriving same data using webview concept after next page i am having one button print if i click on print button it will print my retrived data.In my webview if i click the print button it won't working also.

Comment: Okay, now i get your question competely. But I am not sure of the answer.